# Recursively traverse HashMap?

Tags: java, algorithm

Is there a way to recursively traverse a `HashMap` so that `value1` of `key1` is actually the new `key2` which returns `value2` that again will be the next `key3` and so on ... till it returns `null`? The logic is as follows:

```
hm.get(key)
hm.get(hm.get(key))
hm.get(hm.get(hm.get(key)))
......
```

I'm assuming this may be done through some recursion procedure? Please correct me if I were wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. It is designed that way. Would you give some code? Either a loop or a recursion? Thanks!

Comment: I moved my comment into an answer with code.

Comment: If the end result is always null, you'd better write `String endValue = null` rather than using your algorithm. What's the point of "traversing" a map if you don't do anything with every value?

Comment: i would go with jammy answer, but want to know one thing, is it right way to use hash-map, of-course logically it would be possible

Comment: Beware of infinite loops. Beware of infinite loops. Beware of infinite loops.

Comment: @JBNizet The goal was to return a chain sequence such as: key->value->key->value->...

Comment: @trinithis Yah, this is based on we know the chain will get to an end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the one you wanted procedure? it will return the ultimate value by traversing the hashmap:

```
 Public Object traverseMap(Object key)
    while(hm.get(key) != null){
      key = hm.get(key);
    }
    return key;
 }
```

Comment: *"... it will return the ultimate value"* - unless there is a cycle, in which case this will result in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

If the hashmap would be set up this way (i.e. it contains a value which is also the key for another value) it would be possible. You could do that in a recursive method but a loop would be sufficient:

```
Object key = someInitialKey;
Object value = null;
do {
  value = hm.get( key );
  key = value;
} while( value != null );
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, anyway, that's the (tail!) recursive version you asked for:

```
public class Qsdf {

    public static Object traverseMap(Map m, Object key) {
        return traverseMap(m, key, new HashSet());
    }

    public static Object traverseMap(Map m, Object key, Set traversed) {
        if (key == null) { // first key has to be null
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        traversed.add(key);
        Object value = m.get(key);
        if (traversed.contains(value)) { // added after Stephen C's comment on other answer
            // cycle found, either throw exception, return null, or return key
            return key;
        }
        return value != null ?
                traverseMap(m, value, traversed) :
                key; // I guess you want to return the last value that isn't also a key
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final HashMap<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        m.put(0, 1);
        m.put(1, 2);
        m.put(3, 4);
        m.put(2, 3);
        final Object o = traverseMap(m, 0);
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```